# Delphi 7 - selectdirectory wont compile

Tags: delphi-7

I am trying to use the overloaded version of `FileCtrl.SelectDirectory()`:

```pascal
function SelectDirectory(const Caption: string; const Root: WideString; var Directory: string; Options: TSelectDirExtOpts = [sdNewUI]; Parent: TWinControl = nil): Boolean; overload;
```

I want to include the `sdNewUI` option but cannot get my code to compile:

```
procedure TRecDataForm.DirButtonClick(Sender: TObject);
var
  sdNew: TSelectDirExtOpt;
begin
  chosenDirectory := 'C:\';
  if selectdirectory(chosenDirectory, [sdNewUI], 0) then
    DirLabel.Caption := chosenDirectory;
end;
```

Any working code out there?

Comment: *cannot get my code to compile* means that you're getting at least one compiler error, It's much easier to help when you include that exact error message in your question.

Answer (score 1):

Your code is calling the 1st overloaded version of `SelectDirectory()`:

```pascal
function SelectDirectory(var Directory: string; Options: TSelectDirOpts; HelpCtx: Longint): Boolean;
```

But it is trying to pass the `sdNewUI` flag in the `Options` parameter.  That flag is not valid for a `TSelectDirOpts`, which is why the code will not compile.  It is only valid for a `TSelectDirExtOpts`, which is used by the 2nd overloaded version of `SelectDirectory()`:

```pascal
function SelectDirectory(const Caption: string; const Root: WideString; var Directory: string; Options: TSelectDirExtOpts = [sdNewUI]; Parent: TWinControl = nil): Boolean; overload;
```

Your code should look like this instead:

```pascal
procedure TRecDataForm.DirButtonClick(Sender: TObject);
var
  chosenDirectory: string;
begin
  chosenDirectory := 'C:\';
  if SelectDirectory('Select a Directory', '', chosenDirectory, [sdNewUI], Self) then
    DirLabel.Caption := chosenDirectory;
end;
```

**UPDATE**: turns out that `TSelectDirExtOpts` was introduced in Delphi 2005, which means you can't use the `sdNewUI` flag in Delphi 7. So, you will have to omit the 2 new parameters that were added to that overload of `SelectDirectory()` (which itself does exist in Delphi 7):

```pascal
procedure TRecDataForm.DirButtonClick(Sender: TObject);
var
  chosenDirectory: string;
begin
  chosenDirectory := 'C:\';
  if SelectDirectory('Select a Directory', '', chosenDirectory) then
    DirLabel.Caption := chosenDirectory;
end;
```

Or else you will have to use either:

- the [`TBrowseForFolder`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/Vcl.StdActns.TBrowseForFolder) action (if it is available in Delphi 7):

```pascal
uses
  ..., StdActns;

procedure TRecDataForm.DirButtonClick(Sender: TObject);
var
  dlg: TBrowseForFolder;
begin
  dlg := TBrowseForFolder.Create(nil);
  try
    dlg.Folder := 'C:\';
    dlg.BrowseOptions := [bifReturnOnlyFSDirs, bifUseNewUI]; // use desired flags as needed...

    if dlg.Execute then
      DirLabel.Caption := dlg.Folder;
  finally
    dlg.Free;
  end;
end;
```

- the Win32 [`SHBrowseForFolder()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/shlobj_core/nf-shlobj_core-shbrowseforfoldera) function directly:

```pascal
function BrowseCallback(hWnd: HWND; uMsg: UINT; lParam: LPARAM; lpData: LPARAM): Integer; stdcall;
begin
  if (uMsg = BFFM_INITIALIZED) and
     (lpData <> 0) and
     (PWideChar(lpData)^ <> WideChar(0)) then
  begin
    SendMessage(hWnd, BFFM_SETSELECTION, TRUE, lpData);
  end;
  Result := 0;
end;

procedure TRecDataForm.DirButtonClick(Sender: TObject);
var
  defaultDirectory: WideString;
  chosenDirectory: array[0..MAX_PATH] of Char;
  bfi: TBrowseInfo;
  pidl: PItemIDList;
begin
  defaultDirectory := 'C:\';

  ZeroMemory(@bfi, sizeof(bfi));
  bfi.hwndOwner := Handle;
  bfi.ulFlags := BIF_RETURNONLYFSDIRS or BIF_USENEWUI; // use desired flags as needed...
  bfi.lpfn := @BrowseCallback;
  bfi.lParam := LPARAM(PWideChar(defaultDirectory));

  pidl := SHBrowseForFolder(bfi);
  if pidl <> nil then
  try
    if SHGetPathFromIDList(pidl, chosenDirectory) then
      DirLabel.Caption := chosenDirectory;
  finally
    CoTaskMemFree(pidl);
  end;
end;
```

Comment: Thanks.But I am still getting a " Too many actual parameters" Error on compile. Perhaps this function is platform specific. I am runninh Win 10 and Delphi7.

Comment: @TarryWaterson Not platform-specific, but version-specific. See the update I made to my answer